# how do i properly close cursor in loop body because i m getting ERROR: java.sql.SQLException: - ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded

Tags: java, oracle

I have been encountered with ORA-01000 SQL exception since following code fetches more than thousand records, so in this regard i would like to know that how do i close ResultSet objects appropriately in loop body so that i may get rid of this exception. Please help me out ... it would b really appreciated ...

Note:-Even though I have opened 2000 cursors in Oracle database.

```
try
    {
        String usercode = session.get("usercode").toString();
        Date dor = null;
        Date eff_date =null;
        String emp_category_code = "";
        String emp_id = "";
        String pay_com = "";
        double new_da = 0;
        double old_da =0;
        int caseCount =0;
         con = DBConnect.makeconnect();
         con.setAutoCommit(false);
         String div_name = session.get("division").toString();
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select emp_id ,category,pay_comm,da as old_da,nvl(pm.EMP_DOR,pm.EMP_DOD) as dor from ABC pm where pm.DIV_NM  = ? and sent_to_trea= '1'");
        ps.setString(1,div_name);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            emp_id = rs.getString("emp_id");
            emp_category_code = rs.getString("category");
            pay_com = rs.getString("pay_comm");
            dor = rs.getDate("dor");
            old_da = rs.getDouble("old_da");

            ps = con.prepareStatement("select eff_date,per_amount from XYZ where  cat_code=? and relief='DA' and  eff_date=(select max(EFF_DATE) from XYZ where PAY_COM=? and cat_code=?) and pay_com=?");
            ps.setString(1, emp_category_code);
            ps.setString(2, pay_com);
            ps.setString(3, emp_category_code);
            ps.setString(4, pay_com);
            ResultSet rst = ps.executeQuery();
            if(rst.next())
            {
               eff_date = rst.getDate("eff_date");
                new_da = rst.getDouble("per_amount");
            }

            ps = con.prepareStatement("select retirement_gratuity from CAL where emp_id = ?");
            ps.setString(1,emp_id);
            rst = ps.executeQuery();
            if(rst.next())
            {
                double ret_grat = rst.getDouble("retirement_gratuity");
                if(ret_grat >=1000000)
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }

            if(dor.compareTo(eff_date)>0)
            {
                if(new_da >old_da)
                {
                    ps = con.prepareStatement("select emp_id from AFFECTET where emp_id = ?");
                    ps.setString(1,emp_id);
                     rst = ps.executeQuery();
                     if(!rst.next())
                     {
                     ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into upops.AFFECTED (EMP_ID,PREVIOUS_DA,NEW_DA,PREV_GRATUITY,NEW_GRATUITY,REVISION_NO,DONE,EFF_DATE,PAY_COMM,CATEGORY) (select pm.emp_id,pm.da," + new_da + ",c.RETIREMENT_GRATUITY,0,0,'N',to_date('"+eff_date+"','yyyy-MM-dd'),pm.pay_comm,pm.category from upops.pensioner_mast pm ,upops.calculation c where c.emp_id=pm.emp_id and pm.emp_id = '"+emp_id+"')");
                    int executeUpdate = ps.executeUpdate();
                    if (executeUpdate > 0) {
                         ret = CheckUtils.fileMovement(emp_id,usercode , "33", con);
                        if (ret.equals("SUCCESS")) {
                            caseCount++;
                        }
                    }
                     }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }

         rst.close();

        }
         ret = "SUCCESS";
       if(ret.equals("SUCCESS"))
       {
           con.commit();
       }


    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();;
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){}
    }
```

Comment: Close each `ResultSet` after you are finished reading it.

Comment: yes i did but its not working in my code .. can u plzz make ur suggestion more specific by putting correct code .... plz plz @Jim Garrison

Comment: I see no attempts to close a ResultSet in the code you posted.  I'm not sure what you mean by "I did" unless you've posted an older version of the code.

Comment: yes its older version of code ... let me tell u what i did .. i have written rst.close();  statement at the end of loop body bcz i think created cursor object will be closed after every loop iteration but this way also triggers same Exception ..... u can see my new posted code @justin

Comment: Instead of manually closing `Connection`, `PreparedStatement`, and `ResultSet`, use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Not only will it correctly close the resources for you, it also encourages better code structure. --- For example, you never close `rs`, and you **reuse** `rst` so you never close the first two instances.

Comment: You need the close call every time you finish reading the `ResultSet`.  You open a new ResultSet and assign it to the variable `rst` several times in your code.  That's a bad idea.  Variables should have meaningful names, `rs` and `rst` are not meaningful.  Use something that identifies what the data is.  Don't just keep re-using `rst` for half a dozen different ResultSet's.  If you are going to re-use `rst`, close the prior `ResultSet` before you open a new one.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to use the `Java 7` and above, I prefer you to use `try with resources` which was introduced in `Java 7` new features.

`Try-with-resources` in `Java 7` is a new `exception handling` mechanism that makes it easier to correctly close `resources` that are used within a `try-catch block.`

As to your code:

```
finally
    {
        try
        {
            con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){}
    }
```

**Do you notice that ugly double try?**

But, if you used the `try with resources` , `close()` is automatically called, if it throws an Exception or not, it will be supressed [(as specified in the Java Language Specification 14.20.3)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3) . Same happens for your Database connection and resources case.

Eg.: (JDBC with `try with resources`)

```
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(yourConnectionURL);
         PreparedStatement ps = createPreparedStatement(con, userId); 
         ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {

         // process the resultset here, all resources will be cleaned up

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

private PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con, int userId) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE id = ?";
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setInt(1, userId);
    return ps;
}
```